# position vectors of the vertices of a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: vector-spaces

If A,B,C,D are position vectors of the vertices of a cyclic quadrilateral ABCD then we have to prove that 
[image]

I took the origin as centre of the circle .

Then magnitude of each vector is r .

Now how can I proceed .

Comment: And please don't keep tagging vector spaces. Use the vectors tag.

Comment: Sorry , I will not do it again @Rohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\tan A =\frac {\sin A}{\cos A} =\frac {\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{AD}}{\overrightarrow  {AB}\cdot \overrightarrow  {AD}}$$ $$ = \frac {(\vec b -\vec a)\times (\vec d - \vec a)}{(\vec b- \vec a)\cdot (\vec d-\vec a)} $$ $$= \frac {|\vec a\times \vec b+\vec b\times \vec d+\vec d \times \vec a|}{(\vec b-\vec a)\cdot (\vec d-\vec a)} $$ Similarly, we can show that the second term equals $\tan C $. We thus need to prove that $$\tan A +\tan C =0 \implies \sin (A+C)=0 \implies A+C =\pi $$ which is true as $ABCD $ is cyclic. Hope it helps.